# Cannot determine where the base constructor is called, signing the event

Tags: c#, events, inheritance, constructor, delegates

So, here is my code. The output is 2255. But I caanot understand why method in class A will be executed, for we haven't signed the event on it, as we haven't created an instance of class A.

```
using System;
public delegate void EvHappened();
class A{
    protected int a = 0;
    public event EvHappened AEv;
    public A() {
        this.AEv += EvAHappenedHandler;
    }
    public void EvAHappenedHandler(){
        if (a > 3)
            this.a++;
        Console.Write(a);
    }
    public void methodA() {
        this.AEv();
    }
}

class B : A{
    public event EvHappened BEv;
    public void EvBHappenedHandler() {
        this.a += 2; methodA(); Console.Write(a);
    }
    public void method(){
        this.BEv();
    }
}
class Program{
    static void Main(string[] args){
        B b = new B();
        b.BEv += b.EvBHappenedHandler;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            b.method();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not on terminology: there's no such thing as "signing" an event - did you mean "subscribing to" the event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pure **OOP**:

When you create object B which inherits class A. The Constructor for A will be called.

**Example:**

```
class A
{
    public A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Constructor Of A");
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Constructor Of B");
    }

    public void method()
    {

    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
B b = new B();
```

**Output:**

```
Constructor Of A
Constructor Of B
```

## **If you really need to Create class `B` without running the Constructor:**

```
B b = (B)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(B));
```

Note: You should not use this unless you know what you are doing, as per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true).

> Because the new instance of the object is initialized to zero and no
>   constructors are run, the object might not represent a state that is
>   regarded as valid by that object. The current method should only be
>   used for deserialization when the user intends to immediately populate
>   all fields. It does not create an uninitialized string, since creating
>   an empty instance of an immutable type serves no purpose.

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't declared any constructors in `B`, the compiler has provided a default constructor - it's as if you'd written:

```
public class B {
    public B() : base() {
    }

    // Rest of class here
}
```

So when you call `new B()`, the `A` constructor will be executed. That constructor subscribes to the `AEv` event.

If you *had* declared a constructor yourself, the behaviour would depend on the *constructor initializer*:

- With a constructor initializer of the form `this(...)`, the constructor would chain to another constructor in the same class. Eventually this "chain" will end up with a call to a constructor in the base class.
- With a constructor initializer of the form `base(...)`, the constructor would chain to the specified constructor in the base class.
- If you don't specify a constructor initializer at all, it's equivalent to one of the form `base()`.

So whatever you do in the derived class, any constructor always ends up going through a constructor in the base class.

Comment: Even if you create a constructor for B, the constructor for A will be called.

Comment: @user3185569: I've expanded my answer to make that more explicit.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks Jon. It was a little bit confusing at first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Class A's constructor is called when you instantiate Class B

```
B b = new B();
```

which in turn, registers the handler. The design of Class A is basically saying that derived classes have no right to change the inherited behaviour. If you want the opposite at least make `EvAHappenedHandler` virtual.